# automatically adjusting height

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

just wondering can someone help, 
http://limerickchambers.hailstormcommerce.com/services/international-trade-services/
Here I want the blue border on the right to always match the height of the sidebar on the left, `min-height` doesnt work because the sidebar on the left changes all time. Ive tried `height:100%` but that doesnt stretch it out.
They're both wrapped in a div called `content` and Ive given that a height of `auto` which I was hoping would work but no luck. And I dont want to go down the road of `position:absolute` to get that working.

So I have:

```
.entry-content {
    border:1px solid #d4d9ed;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:0px 20px 10px 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:1056px;
}
```

Inside of:

```
.page-content-right {
    color: #CACACA;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 18px;
    width: 710px;
}
```

Which is inside of:

```
.singular #content, .left-sidebar.singular #content {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used jQuery in the end.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var leftHeight = jQuery('.content-sidebar-new').height();

jQuery('.entry-content').css({'min-height':leftHeight - 31});
});
```

Comment: If this is the answer to your question, then well and good! If not, and if it's an extension and better explanation of your question, then I suggest you copy this and edit your question above and delete it. It might be misleading.

Comment: well its the answer in that it worked for me in the end.  Thats why I dont want to put it in the original post, as it would contain the answer already no?